# Vertical alignment of a div element in container

Tags: html, vertical-alignment

I am trying to understand why vertical alignment of an element in div container goes to bottom of the parent when max-heigh is set below 100%. When I click div.first it sets either class name short or long to next  element. Class name short sets max-width of 3em. Class name long sets max-width to 100%. However, when class name is set to short while class name of other elements is set to long the div with class name short aligns itself to the bottom of the container. How to make it positions to the top of the parent?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="letters-hoder">

        <div class="letter" >
            <div class="first" id="a">A</div>              
            <div >
            <ul id="a-ul" class="short">
                <li>Apple</li>
                <li>Amazon</li>
                <li>Alphabet</li>
                <li>Analog Devices</li>
                <li>Applied Materials</li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="letter" >
            <div class="first" id="b">B</div>              
            <div>
                <ul id="b-ul" class="short">
                    <li>Broadcom</li>
                    <li>Booking.com</li>
                    <li>Bank of America</li>
                    <li>Boeing</li>
                    <li>Biogen</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


</div>
    <script>

    let letters = document.getElementsByClassName('first')

    for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        letters[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
    }

        function handleClick(evt){            
                       
            let checkElement = document.getElementById(evt.target.id + "-ul")
            console.log(checkElement)
            if(checkElement.className ==="long"){
                checkElement.className="short"
            }else{
                checkElement.className="long"
            }
        }

    </script>

    <style>
        
        div.first{
            background-color: rgb(246, 247, 223);
            font-weight: bold;
            padding-left:5px;
            padding-top:2px;
            padding-bottom:2px;
        }

        div.letter{
            margin-left:10px;
            border:1px solid lightgray;
            border-radius: 5px;
    
        }

        div.letters-hoder{
            display:flex;
            align-items:start;
        }
        
     
        ul{
            margin-top: 0;
            padding-left:0;
            list-style-type: none;            
            overflow:hidden;
            
        }

        ul.short{
             max-height:4em;
        }

        ul.long{
             max-height:100%;
        }

        li{
            margin-left:0px;
            margin-right:0px;
            margin-top:2px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid white;
            transition: 100ms;
            padding-left:5px;
            padding-right:5px;
        }


        div.letter{
            display: inline-block;
            
        }

        li:hover{            
            cursor:pointer;
            border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;            
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS it will work.

```
#letters-hoder{
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```